# How can I launch a blocking task from asyncio asynchronously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am new to asyncio and am attempting to make a simple webserver that, upon receiving a request, calculates a chess move and returns the result as a response. The problem is, the process is blocking, making it so that the webserver cannot listen and react to requests while it is evaluating. I feel like I am very close, but am unable to figure out the next few steps to make this work properly. I have gotten the chess engine to run in several different threads with another script, now I just need to know how to integrate that into a simple web server. Any help with this would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
import chess.engine
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import json

engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("/usr/games/stockfish")

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)


def play():
    global engine
    fen = "rnbqkbnr/pp1ppppp/8/2p5/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R b KQkq - 1 2"
    print(fen)
    board = chess.Board(fen)    
    result = engine.play(board,chess.engine.Limit(time=15.0))
    return result

async def run_blocking_task(executor):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, play)
    return result

async def hello(request):
    result = await run_blocking_task(executor)
    return web.Response(text=str(result.move))


app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', hello)])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
handler = app.make_handler()
f = loop.create_server(handler, '0.0.0.0', 8080)
srv = loop.run_until_complete(f)
print('serving on', srv.sockets[0].getsockname())
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(handler.finish_connections(1.0))
    srv.close()
    loop.run_until_complete(srv.wait_closed())
    loop.run_until_complete(app.finish())
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Overall your code looks fine. The issue you are running into is Pythons limited threading support.

Try swapping the `ThreadPoolExecutor` for a `ProcessPoolExecutor` (`from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor`) this will run your engine task in a separate process allowing the task to actually run in parallel.

To expand on the threading issue, the Python interpreter has a lock (known as the GIL) that only allows Python code to be executed on one thread at a time. This greatly simplifies the majority of development tasks. The lock is released under certain conditions, calls to the Kernel to perform IO (either reading from a file or network) release the GIL, making IO a good use-case for threading. The `ProcessPoolExecutor` executes your worker task in a separate process with its own separate interpreter allowing your code to run in parallel, this approach comes with some overhead but in the context of modern computers, this is fairly minimal. The `ProcessPoolExecutor` will automatically handle the process of moving data between each process for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tim. That certainly seems like a step in the right direction - I tried swapping out the ThreadPoolExecutor for a ProcessPoolExecutor, but two things happened (or didn't happen):

1. The code is still blocking. Sending 2 requests to the server simultaneously, one would start only after the other has finished.

2. The client does not receive a response. It seems like moving the work to another process has made the server lose the reference to the request it was supposed to respond to, or something. Not entirely sure.