# Trouble in Optimizing asyncio with concurrent futures

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to run asyncio task concurrently on each worker thread of concurrent.futures Threadpool. However, I couldn't achieve the desired outcome.

```
async def say_after(delay, message):
    logging.info(f"{message} received")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    logging.info(f"Printing {message}")

async def main():
    logging.info("Main started")
    await asyncio.gather(say_after(2, "TWO"), say_after(3, "THREE"))
    logging.info("Main Ended")

await main()
```

`Output:`

```
20:12:26:MainThread:Main started
20:12:26:MainThread:TWO received
20:12:26:MainThread:THREE received
20:12:28:MainThread:Printing TWO
20:12:29:MainThread:Printing THREE
20:12:29:MainThread:Main Ended
```

To summarize my understanding of above code, asyncio gather creates tasks and registers them on running event loop on MainThread. Unsurprisingly, it saves time as compared to synchronous code.

```
def say_after(delay, message):
    logging.info(f"{message} received")
    time.sleep(delay)
    logging.info(f"Printing {message}")

with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    results = [executor.submit(say_after, i+1, num_word_mapping[i+1]) for i in range(10)]
```

To summarize my understanding, cf threadpool creates three threads which are swapped preemptively by OS to achieve concurrency.

`Output:`

```
19:38:43:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_0:ONE received
19:38:43:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_1:TWO received
19:38:43:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_2:THREE received
19:38:44:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_0:Printing ONE
19:38:44:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_0:FOUR received
19:38:45:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_1:Printing TWO
19:38:45:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_1:FIVE received
19:38:46:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_2:Printing THREE
19:38:46:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_2:SIX received
19:38:48:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_0:Printing FOUR
19:38:48:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_0:SEVEN received
19:38:50:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_1:Printing FIVE
19:38:50:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_1:EIGHT received
19:38:52:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_2:Printing SIX
19:38:52:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_2:NINE received
19:38:55:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_0:Printing SEVEN
19:38:55:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_0:TEN received
19:38:58:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_1:Printing EIGHT
19:39:01:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_2:Printing NINE
19:39:05:ThreadPoolExecutor-9_0:Printing TEN
```

Now I want to run an event loop with multiple tasks on each worker thread. I tried below code but it didn't improve the execution time.

```
def say_after(delay, message):
    logging.info(f"{message} received")
    time.sleep(delay)
    logging.info(f"Printing {message}")

async def parallel(executor, delay, message):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.run_in_executor(executor, say_after, delay, message) 

async def main():
    executor = cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    await asyncio.gather(*[parallel(executor, i+1, num_word_mapping[i+1])  for i in range(10)])

await main()
```

`Output:`

```
20:57:04:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_0:ONE received
20:57:04:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_1:TWO received
20:57:04:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_2:THREE received
20:57:05:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_0:Printing ONE
20:57:05:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_0:FOUR received
20:57:06:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_1:Printing TWO
20:57:06:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_1:FIVE received
20:57:07:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_2:Printing THREE
20:57:07:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_2:SIX received
20:57:09:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_0:Printing FOUR
20:57:09:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_0:SEVEN received
20:57:11:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_1:Printing FIVE
20:57:11:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_1:EIGHT received
20:57:13:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_2:Printing SIX
20:57:13:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_2:NINE received
20:57:16:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_0:Printing SEVEN
20:57:16:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_0:TEN received
20:57:19:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_1:Printing EIGHT
20:57:22:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_2:Printing NINE
20:57:26:ThreadPoolExecutor-19_0:Printing TEN
```

I expected to see faster execution times in code 4. However, I am not sure if I am doing it in the right way.

`Environment:` Python 3.7 (Jupyter Notebook)

Comment: Swap `ThreadPoolExecutor` for a `ProcessPoolExecutor`.
See my answer here for a more complete answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992595/how-can-i-launch-a-blocking-task-from-asyncio-asynchronously/57024393#57024393

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to run an event loop with multiple tasks on each worker thread.

Concurrent workers are completely separate from the event loop. Each pool consists of a number of workers, and each worker can do **one** job at any given time. This functionality is provided by the `concurrent.futures` module and is completely orthogonal to asyncio.

So, when you use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to **access** the thread pool, there is no reason that the code would magically become faster. After all, you are still executing 10 tasks on 3 workers, just like before. The only value `run_in_executor` has added is that now you can `await` those workers in your asyncio event loop.

To speed up the code, you need to either increase the number of workers, or stop using `run_in_executor` altogether and start using asyncio-native facilities, as in your first example.